# Android OpenCV views other that CameraBridgeViewBase

Tags: android, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

Many of the examples available online show how to acquire and process an image from camera using `CameraBridgeViewBase`.

I would like to create a simple app that only one `ImageView` and several menu options for formatting that ImageView such as grayscale, sepia, etc.

The problem I have is how to enable OpenCV functionality on menu item click without using `CameraBridgeViewBase`.

Right now the following code is used to enable camera:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            }
                break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Question: is there something similar to `mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();` that just uses image from the ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the required functionality by setting background on OpenCvCameraView.